# How would I use Keras.backend.function( ) to find the predictions of each training batch?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, callback

I'm building a custom metric in Tensorflow, but in order to calculate it, I need the following data extracted at the end of each training batch:

- The probability predictions of each class
- The row indices of the batch data within the original training dataset

As long as I have this, my metric can be calculated.

I've tried to use Keras.backend.function() to calculate this, but I'm not exactly sure how I would use it to get my data of interest.

My code is based off another answer, but I don't know how to tweak it to get what I want:

class CollectKerasSymbolicTensorsCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

```
def __init__(self):
    """Initialize intermediate variables for batches and lists."""
    super().__init__()

    self.outputs = []
    
    self.input = tf.Variable(0.0, shape=tf.TensorShape(None))
    self.output = tf.Variable(0.0, shape=tf.TensorShape(None))
    
    
def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    
    get_output = K.function(inputs = [self.model.layers[0].input], outputs = self.model.layers[-1].output)
    
    self.output.append(get_output(self.model.layers[0].input))
```

callback = CollectKerasSymbolicTensorsCallback()

As you can see above, I defined the inputs and outputs to be tensors, and used the backend.function to define my input as the input batch training data, and the output to be the final prediction.

However, when it comes to calling the function, I'm not sure what to put in the brackets. Here I put self.model.layers[0].input as this is the main input parameter but it doesn't seem to work at all.

My model is structured like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'),
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['categorical_crossentropy'], run_eagerly=True)

model.fit(X, Result, epochs=1, batch_size=256, callbacks = callback)
```

However, I only get the following code in return:

KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='model_69/dense_123/Softmax:0', description="created by layer 'model_69'")

Is there any way to tweak my code so I can read these KerasTensors as data outputs i.e. probability predictions, as well as find the data row indices within each training batch?

Comment: You are massively overthinking the problem, for this just use model.predict or model(inputs)

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I still have an issue with using model(inputs). How do I define the inputs in the first place i.e. the batch that has been modelled on, and how do I use this to get the row index so I can relate it back to the data in the original training set.

Comment: Also I read that input layers are just symbolic tensors, so you can't read them as you would a normal dataset.

Comment: model.predict takes numpy arrays, not symbolic tensors, and you build the data, just a numpy array of whatever you want, you have to keep mapping to your original indices. Keras cannot do this for you.

Comment: So how would I access the batch data so I can map to the correct indices in my training dataset?